# Qt: How can I use my widgets created with code in the *.ui file

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I have a project in Qt made with the QWizard and QWizardPage classes. There are two ways to create a widget i.e: a Label:

1. One is going to the *.ui file and search the element and put it where you want (visual way). Then you can access it on your code with `ui->nameOfLabel`.
2. The other one is going to your code and creating it like `QLabel codedLabel;`

Actually I'm using the second way (it's easier for me to create, show and use) but my question is: **Is there any way that I can see my label codedLabel on the *.ui file?**

I would like to move it to a space in the screen and in that case, it would be much easier for me to be able to do it through the visual way (but having the label created in the code instead of the ui).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why not just use the `ui->nameOfLabel` instead?

Comment: @owacoder Because its a really big project with a lot of widgets and things and, in this case, this  widget will be created only if something happens so I don't want to create it if it's not necessary.

Comment: I think any widget placed in Qt Designer forms must be in memory throughout the lifespan of the application. If you have a temporary widget, you would probably have to place that in a layout yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets created at runtime from your source code and being added to a widget as child CANNOT be seen in Qt Designer when you edit the .ui file of the widget they will be added to.

However, there could be an alternative (reading what you are trying to achieve: having some child widgets being present or not based on the context):

Create the widget from the .ui within Qt Designer and hide it (`QWidget::hide()`) or even remove it (`QLayout::removeWidget()`) programmatically if not needed at runtime.

If the real reason why you want to see it is because you want to "*move it to a space in the screen and in that case, it would be much easier for me to be able to do it through the visual way*". Then I recommend that you simply create an empty `QWidget` (or `QLayout`) in Qt Designer (graphically: easy to place where you want to) and later (programmatically) add your `QLabel` to it (rather than adding it to the main top-level widget): then, it goes in the place you determined from Qt Designer tool.

You should not need any complex code to programmatically display your QLabel in a specific place, just choose the right parent to have it be displayed in the right place!